# Where is the link for new questions?

Tags: support, design

Have I gone blind? I can't find a link to get to the newest questions in the new GUI. Sure I can type in `/questions` but I shouldn't have to.

Perhaps it is in the sidebar (which I've hidden because it was huge and distracting to me).

https://stackoverflow.com/ menu contains Interesting, featured, hot, week, month
https://stackoverflow.com/questions menu contains **Newest**, featured, frequent, votes, active, unanswered

Comment: If you had just clicked around a bit you could've found it

Comment: @coldspeed ... or not - I've hidden the sidebar because I'm one of those unfortunates who gets a huge sidebar for whatever reason. The link under the hamburger doesn't say "Newest" or "Questions", so it is pretty well hidden. Finding a feature that used to be one click on the front page by trial and error? does that seriously sound sensible to you?

Comment: Granted it's not as "intuitive" as the old design, and there are a lot of things about it I don't like. But "hiding" the left nav doesn't mean the menu disappears... it just becomes a part of the dropdown on the sticky navbar. Anyway, I have it hidden as well, and clicking around a bit is how I found it.

Comment: This screwed with my work flow of "search the page for interesting questions until I hit the bottom, hit 'questions', repeat". Now I need to either click the address bar then `enter`, or open the menu then click "Stack Overflow". An extra click isn't a huge deal, but it is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve hidden the left-navigation, so you now have a hamburger menu on the top left of the site, next to the Stack Overflow logo.

The “ Stack Overflow” link links to `/questions`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it's a horrible design decision! Used to be a one click operation and now it isn;t.

Comment: It *is* still a one click option, you just chose not to use that option...

Comment: @Catija So I can have an ugly and distracting sidebar with good functionality or a cleaner GUI with missing functionality? Two great choices... There is plenty of space in the menu area to add a "Newest" option (just like was there until yesterday).

Comment: @John3136 Until yesterday, that was in the top bar and lots of people complained about how the top bar worked and those links being in the top bar and taking up space... which, with the responsive design needs to be even smaller. It's a give and take situation. If you have an alternate solution, by all means, post a request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness :)